# Changing tempo of music track in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, playback

Is it possible to change tempo of music track without using any sound engines like `FMOD` ? I know by changing pitch in AudioSource I can change speed of music but you know by changing pitch actually the music can be completely changed.

Comment: To my knowledge, pitch is the only option unity offers itself.

Comment: Yup, I see. So for changing BPM I need sound engine or separate phrases of music which I can make something in Unity to make sequence of them and control tempo. Am I right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the answer it is the best approach which I've found in Unity. (Actually one of my friends suggest this approach)

1. Create an Audio Mixer (Left click on project Folder > Create > Audio Mixer)
2. Add the Audio Mixer to that `AudioSource` in Output value in the inspector
3. Select the Audio Mixer > Master under his children, click `Add Effect` and select `Pitch shifter`
4. Select the `AudioSource` and set the `Pitch` to 2 (Example)
5. Set the Pitch of the `AudioMixer Pitch` to 0.5 (Example)

The formula for calculating `AudioSource Pitch` and `AudioMixer Pitch`: `AudioMixer Pitch Value = 1 / AudioSource Pitch Value`

- If you are using AudioSource Pitch above of 2 then you need to add another Audio Pitch Shifter in the AudioMixer and set the values for both get original pitch (1)

Comment: Im surprised this answer doesnt have any upvotes (until now) I've been searching unity forums and SO and frankly this has been the easiest, most viable option for updating the tempo of an audio source.

Answer (score 1):

Chanching pitch by changing the playback rate is the only simple way (which obviously also change speed). Theres dozens of algorithms that let you change one without changing the other but 
a) most of them proprietary
b) most of them have nasty artifacts
c) most software that has those options available give you a choice of algorithms to pick from - one of them will sound the least terrible compared to others, at least in theory

In softwares like Ableton Live thres 'advanced' option which basically switches between modes depending on character of the material, which gives believable result within few percent change, but with our hearing being such an important aspect of our awarness within the world, evolutionary we are very sensitive to any slightest alterations.

The most simple stretching algorithms are based on granular synthesis, you split the stream into 'grains' - if you just play them one by one you get your original signal, but if you play them at higher speed (but start them equally spaced in time domain) you can change the pitch without changing speed. The thing is, even with lots of windowing, theres only so much you can do before really nasty artifacts start to show up.

The short answer is no.